# Retrieving data from azure mobile services Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, azure, xamarin

I am new to xamarin, and I am trying to figure out how to retrieve a number to display in a text box. I am using the example azure mobile services for xamarin as a base and trying to modify it for my purposes. my problems occur when I try to retrieve data from a class that is not a TableViewCell. the code below is what I am trying

```
       private async Task RefreshAsync()
    {

        NSIndexPath indexPath = new NSIndexPath();


       var label = new UILabel(new RectangleF(200, 200, 200, 200));
        View.Add(label);
        label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(35);

        while (true)
        {
            int my = todoService.Items2[indexPath.Row].t1;

            RefreshControl.BeginRefreshing();
            await todoService.RefreshDataAsync();
            RefreshControl.EndRefreshing();

            label.Text = my.ToString();
            await Task.Delay(30000);
        }}
```

it does not show any errors, but when it compiles it does not run and throws an exception. is there a way to get the data into a label without using indexpath and update it automatically every 30 seconds? any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I thank you in advance.

Comment: You have an infinite loop inside of an async method that never returns anything.  Have you created an Azure table that contains data?  Repeatedly calling refresh will just return the same data over and over if there is not some other process that is updating the data in Azure.  It is very unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Each time the loop is running it is calling my method that gets the latest data from my mobile service. I have the data under items2 as seen in my code. All I want is to be able to retrieve the single number that is returned through items2 t1 and place it into a text box. If there is a more logical way to go about it I would love to hear! If you need anymore details please let me know. Thank you